# Data migration using PeeWee/Playhouse

Tags: mysql, migration, peewee

In a project I'm consulting on, PeeWee/Playhouse are used for migrations.  This works fine for numerous schema migrations, and for a few static insertions (basically enumerations in a few tables).

However, what I need to accomplish now is to canonicalize some data and write it back into an existing table.  I am unable to find documentation on how I might perform a query, get the results, mutate those, and write them back.

I'd like the code to look something like this (but such doesn't work):

```py
def up():
    values = migrator.raw("SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table")
    mapping = {value: canonical(value) for value in values}
    changes = [f"UPDATE table SET column={new} WHERE column={old}"
               for new, old in mapping.items()]
    migrate(*(migrator.raw(change) for change in changes))
```

The problem is that `values` only seems ever to get a "peewee.SQL object" rather than perform an actual query. (note: I added DISTINCT to query example, which I forgot in hastily typing pseudo-code; in this case with hundreds not millions of rows, it doesn't really matter whether the uniquify is done in Python versus SQL, but the latter is obviously cleaner).

Comment: My questions are 1) why aren't you just using the model to perform the update? 2) why not use a transaction? 3) can you think of a more efficient way to perform such an update? Seems very inefficient to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on why you need to use migrator here at all instead of just using the model directly. Similarly the way you've configured your "mapping" looks very inefficient -- you're not requesting DISTINCT values for `column` so you end up needing to iterate over every single value, canonicalize it, then issue X updates that then must scan for the old value.

Why not just do something like this:

```
with db.atomic() as txn:
    for row in MyModel.select():
        row.value = canonicalize(row.value)
        row.save(only=[MyModel.value])
```